# Guarantee alphabetical sorting without constantly deleting the .order file

Tags: sorting, azure-devops-wiki

**Problem**

In the Azure DevOps wiki I want to have the articles under a specific folder/article always sorted alphabetically

```
Root
  - Other article that is fixed at this position even though it starts with 'Z'
  - Everything under here should always be alphabetically sorted
    - 0
    - A
    - B
    - …
  - Another article that is fixed at this position even though it starts with 'A'
```

**Used (suboptimal) solution**

According to [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/wiki/wiki-file-structure?view=azure-devops#delete-the-order-file-to-revert-to-alphabetical-sorting) an *.order* file will be created in the git repo in the folder *Everything under here should always be alphabetically sorted*. This *.order* file can just be deleted, committed and pushed to revert back to alphabetical sorting. However,

> The .order file gets automatically (re)created after deletion, for example, in a drag and drop action on an article.

There will always be some user that accidentally drags and drops an article to move it (=*.order* file will be created again) or does it on purpose not knowing there is this convention in our wiki.

I added this specific *.order* file to the *.gitignore* but ADO just creates the file again when someone moves an article. Was hoping moving articles just will not be allowed anymore or are reverted on a page reload.

So the current solution is to just daily remove the *.order* file again via pipeline. I don't like this solution as it will create a lot of unnecessary commits making the real commits/changes harder to track.

**Question**

Are there other ways to guarantee the alphabetical sorting or even not allow users to move articles at all?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you presently have no other recourse, and it's a bit more problematic than meets the eye. Addition of a child-page also spawns an unwanted `.order` file - for the parent page/folder.

Microsoft does not acknowledge this as a bug, see [Unwanted, deleted Wiki '.order' files are being regenerated](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Unwanted-deleted-Wiki-order-files-ar/1514090).

Unfortunately, and somewhat comically, I seem to have caused Microsoft to add the verbiage you've cited. It was seemingly added in response to my poorly phrased ticket, [#8966 You should note that removed .order files get recreated](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-devops-docs/issues/8966).

Consider voting for this, [Allow disabling of .order file in wiki subfolders](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/allow-disabling-of-order-file-in-wiki-subfolders/570941). Although, I've heard these are ignored until they receive about 10,000 votes.